# javax.net.ssl.sslhandshakeexception java.security.cert.certificateexception for soap

Tags: java, android, web-services, ssl, soap

I am newbie in Android. I am trying to communicate `.NET` code using web service, but getting error in:

```
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

as:

```
javax.net.ssl.sslhandshakeexception    
java.security.cert.certificateexception
```

[image]

I got to know that because of certification, I am not able to use `saop`. Anyone help me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows an untrusted server-certificate (https is crossed out). Either use a (less secure) http-connection (if possible) or trust the server certificate.

The following JVM parameters might help:

- Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore
- Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
- Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore
- Djavax.net.ssl.tustStorePassword

Comment: that i got it how to remove that ssl in java , when communicate with these type of sites

Comment: You have to use the HTTP protocol, not HTTPS. The protocol is part of the URL. If there is no HTTP version of the webservice, you can use a SSLContext with a truststore, where you explicitly trust the server certificate. Another possibility is to implement your own TrustManager, but that's kind of a security shortcut (not advisable). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/146565/948784 or other examples on stackoverflow.